# MySQL Basic Privileges For Application User / Security

Tags: mysql, database, security, privileges

What is the basic recommended privileges list that I must disable for MySQL user (that created for web application) to make application more secure?

I mean privileges like [FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) and may be other privileges ?

Comment: At first I thought it might be nice to hear answers on this question. Then I realized I must be too tired in thinking that, as it is simply too broad of a question based on your lack of details. We simply don't know what your security requirements are. Please provide the necessary information.

Comment: Perhaps a good comment would be zero privileges, and add them only as necessary without wildcards, piece by piece.

Answer (score 0):

For my situation in phpMyAdmin, this was keeping the 'Data' checkboxes ticked, and the rest of the 'Structure' and 'Administration' options disabled, with the remaining 'Resource Limits' and 'Require SSL' options unchanged.

So this will allow a user to view their information, amend it, remove it, and upload let's say a profile picture.

You may also find these are similar limited permissions when viewing phpmyadmin the cPanel of hosting companies like SiteGround.